# WcfRestContrib: Is there any example of using a WCF REST service (with basic authentication) from a desktop client

Tags: c#, wcf, webhttpbinding, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-contrib

Is there any example of using a WCF REST service  with basic HTTP authentication from a desktop client?
I am using WCF REST Contrib. and authentication works fine when a use a javascript client from the browser, but when I try to use a C# Console app. I get a **BasicUnauthorizedException** {"You have unsuccessfully attempted to access a secure resource."}. even though I supplied the correct username and password.

```
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);
binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:3525/wcfrestdemo/students.svc");

WebChannelFactory<ISudentService> factory =
             new WebChannelFactory<ISudentService>(binding, address);

factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "jon";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "123";

ISudentService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

var response = proxy.GetStudents(2010, 4, 2); //throws an error.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This article on CodeProject answers this questions. **[Basic Authentication on a WCF REST Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/BasicAuthWCFRest.aspx)**